# Second last occurence of an integer in a string (Python)

Tags: python, string, indexing, position

### Second last occurence of an integer in a string

###### Consider "hEY3 a7yY5" as my string, the last integer in this string is 5 and the second last integer is 7.

How do I find index of last second integer in this string?
I'm not sure to if I can use rindex() and if so then how.

The *index* of 7 in the above string is 6.
I can't wrap my head around writing something like `stre.rindex(isnumeric())`

Comment: Is it always a single digit? For example, could the data look like this: hEY3 a73yY5

Comment: The substring can be a number sequence. Like you exemplified, hEY3 a73yY5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find the penultimate occurrence of a sequence of digits in a string and print its offset.

```
import re
a = "hEY3 a7yY5"
offsets = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'\d+', a)]
print(-1 if len(offsets) < 2 else offsets[-2])
```

If you are averse to *re* then you can do it like this:

```
offsets = []

for i, c in enumerate(a):
    if c.isdigit():
        if offsets:
            if offsets[-1] != i - 1:
                offsets.append(i)
        else:
            offsets = [i]
            
print(-1 if len(offsets) < 2 else offsets[-2])
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

Note that the same result would be printed if the string is "hEY7 a75yY5" - i.e., this also handles sequences of more than one digit

Comment: It returns 6 for `hEY7 a75yY5` (second occurrence) while  `hEY33 a77yy55` gives 7(first).

Comment: @Pythonlearner That is correct. That's what it's supposed to do. 7 is the index of the first digit of the penultimate sequence of digits in the string

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this

```
a = "hEY3 a7yy5"
out = [i for i,j in enumerate(a) if j.isnumeric()][-2]
print(out)
```

Comment: Your latest edit induces a TypeError

Comment: Have you considered what would happen if the string contained more than one digit in a sequence - e.g., "hEY33 a77yy55". Your code would return 11 but the correct result should be 7

Comment: This is the most readable and simplest answer. The only catch is that it is counting index separately when a number sequence occurs in the string as it is iterating one by one. Is there anyway to improve this method to detect a number sequence?

Answer (score 1):

An option to get the index of the second last digit using a pattern, and use the start() method of the [Match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) object:

```
s = "hEY3 a7yY5"
pattern = r"\d(?=[^\d\n]*\d[^\d\n]*\Z)"

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.start())
```

Output

```
6
```

The pattern matches:

- `\d` Match a single digit
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is

  - `[^\d\n]*` Optionally match any char except a digit or a newline
  - `\d` Match a single digit
  - `[^\d\n]*` Optionally match any char except a digit or a newline
  - `\Z` End of string
- `)` Close the lookahead